# Java generify DTO classes

Tags: java, inheritance, refactoring, dto

I have three classes two of them extend the base class they look like this:

```
public class AllowanceDTO extends BaseExpenseDTO {
    private String flight;
}

public class CarTravelDTO extends BaseExpenseDTO {
    private Double tripLength;
}

public class BaseExpenseDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int count = 0;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private String typeName;
}
```

These dto's are part of TravelItemDTO

```
public class TravelItemDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;
    private List<BaseExpenseDTO> expenseCompensations;
    private List<AllowanceDTO> allowanceCompensations;
    private List<CarTravelDTO> mileageCompensations;
}
```

How i could generify these dto's ? For exmaple i wouldn't have three lists but one list instead because one TravelItemDTO can have only one type compensation list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, you can generify the `TravelItemDTO`:

```
public class TravelItemDTO<T extends BaseExpenseDTO> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;
    private List<T> compensations;
}
```

Then use it, for example:

```
TravelItemDTO<CarTravelDTO> carTravelItem = new TravelItemDTO<CatTravelItem>();
...
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards:

```
public class TravelItemDTO implements Serializable {
    private List<? extends BaseExpenseDTO> compensations;
//...
}
```

Example:

```
TravelItemDTO dto = new TravelItemDTO();
dto.setCompensations(new ArrayList<AllowanceDTO>());
```

Comment: This proposal is valid but does not answer the "one `TravelItemDTO` can have only one type compensation list" requirement. This way the compensations list can store any sub-type of `BaseExpenseDTO`.